# help with Ruby's fastCSV, need to have empty comma locations

Tags: ruby, csv, fastercsv

My CSV is like:

```
username, lastname, firstname, age, weight, location
```

If I don't have a value, I need to have just the comma with no data like:

```
blankman, man, blank,,,usa
```

Right now I have:

```
blankman, man, blank, '','',usa
```

Because I am doing this like:

```
users = User.....


users.each { |user|

   age = ''


   csv << [ ...   ,age, ... ]


}
```

If I left the variable `age` uninitialized, then I got an error.

not sure what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `age = nil`.